# codeigniter direct download inside application directory

Tags: codeigniter

I have a directory called `storage` inside codeigniter application directory.  I want to create direct download to files in this directory.  What i currently do is the below function but this isn't direct download.

```
function download_file($id){
        $this->load->helper('download');
        $data = file_get_contents(APPPATH . 'storage/videos/'.$id.'.mp4'); // Read the file's contents
        force_download($id.'.mp4', $data);
    }
```

Some of these files are gigabytes, how do i generate a direct link to these files?

Answer (score 0):

See the code for creating link for direct download

```
<a href = "<?= base_url('storage/videos/'.$id.'.mp4') ?>" download ><?= $id.'.mp4' ?></a>
```